# Replace a character in a string VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, substring

I can replace characters by `Replace()` but this function replaces all characters, I want only one of them.

For example:

`1.234.45` or `123.450.55`

I want to replace the last `.` to `,` to get: `1.234,45`, `123.450,55`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is using a `StringBuilder` and `String.LastIndexOf` to replace the char at the index:

```
Dim number = "1.234.45"
Dim lastIndex = number.LastIndexOf(".")
If lastIndex >= 0 Then
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder(number)
    builder(lastIndex) = ","
    Number = builder.ToString()
End If
```

Comment: thanks my friend, this is better to use :)

Comment: `Mid(number, lastIndex + 1, 1) = ","`

Comment: @GSerg: That does not work, strings are immutable. Anyway, why not using .NET methods?

Comment: @TimSchmelter That [does work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/mid-statement), but yes, strings are immutable.

Comment: @GSerg: Maybe works according to documentation, i can just check in LinqPad where it doesn't compile(`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Mid(number, lastIndex + 1, 1) = ","`). But i trust you that it works. Interesting, didn't know that `Mid` can do that

Comment: @GSerg: read about how how Mid makes it possible, it creates a new string and the re-assigns the old variable to the new string. So afterwards ReferenceEquals returns `false`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, it does. I never said there was magic to it :)